# Issues with Show/Hide Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am praying someone can help me with a Show/Hide JavaScript function.

I am building a tool for a website which has an image of a house and buttons to change the colours of the doors, windows etc.

The problem i am having is that when a button is pressed to change the colour of the door, window etc there is a flash of white from the background image.

The original image has white doors, windows etc so my js function loops through the door alpha images (divs) on a button press and changes to the appropriate div with the selected colour but flashes the original base image (div) of the white door in between.

I need to get rid of this white flash so the colours change nicely.

P.s. Once I have pressed all the buttons and changed all the colours the white background is not flashing anymore. So my issue is connected with memory?

D1
      D2
      D3
      D4
      D5
      D6
      D7
      D8
      D9
      D10
      D11
      D12
      D13

```js
let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection-door button");
for (let button of Buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const et = e.target;
    const active = document.querySelector(".active");


    if (active) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
    }

    et.classList.add("active");

    let allContent = document.querySelectorAll('.content-door');

    for (let content of allContent) {

      if (content.getAttribute('data-t') === button.getAttribute('data-t')) {
        content.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.outer {
  margin: 100px;
}

.tool-image-container {
  border: 20px solid #969696;
  height: 700px;
  width: 933px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.base {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.alpha {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 700px;
  width: 933px;
}

.content-door {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-image-container">

  <div class="base-div">
    <img src="base.png" class="base">
  </div>



  <div class="contentSection-door">
    <div class="content-door" data-t="13"><img src="images/door/d13.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="12"><img src="images/door/d12.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="11"><img src="images/door/d11.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="10"><img src="images/door/d10.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="9"><img src="images/door/d9.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="8"><img src="images/door/d8.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="7"><img src="images/door/d7.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="6"><img src="images/door/d6.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="5"><img src="images/door/d5.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="4"><img src="images/door/d4.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="3"><img src="images/door/d3.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="2"><img src="images/door/d2.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="1"><img src="images/door/d1.png" class="alpha"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="selectSection-door">
    <button type="button" data-t="1">D1</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="2">D2</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="3">D3</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="4">D4</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="5">D5</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="6">D6</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="7">D7</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="8">D8</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="9">D9</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="10">D10</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="11">D11</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="12">D12</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="13">D13</button>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to the responsive web era. Why are you using `width` defined in PX units?

Comment: PS. It's a really bad practice to assign click handlers (define functions) inside a for loop. Use a call to function instead. `Buttons.forEach(myFn);` Bam.

Comment: Roko.. I aim to solve that later (widths)

Comment: granted i can't see your whole page from that snippet, but i have my best results when i hide everything first then show the one thing i want to show.  You won't get any flickering.

Comment: Hi John. Here is a full fiddle. Can you see the flashing of the white background when pressing the buttons to change the colour of the door? https://jsfiddle.net/kdtwbfa7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix to your problem is replacing the loop with an attribute selector:

```js
let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection-door button");
for (let button of Buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const et = e.target;
    const active = document.querySelector(".active");


    if (active) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
    }

    et.classList.add("active");
    let activeDoor = document.querySelector('.activeDoor');
    
    //Remove acrive class from door
    if(activeDoor){
      activeDoor.classList.remove("activeDoor");
    }
    console.log(et.dataset.t)
    //Use the data from the button as part of the attribute selector
    //Using the template litteral instead of concatenating 
    document.querySelector(`[data-t='${et.dataset.t}'].content-door`).classList.add("activeDoor");
    
  });
}
```

```css
.outer {
  margin: 100px;
}

.tool-image-container {
  border: 20px solid #969696;
  height: 700px;
  width: 933px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.base {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*Was blocking the buttons*/
  top:20px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.alpha {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9;
  height: 700px;
  width: 933px;
}

.content-door:not(.activeDoor) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-image-container">

  <div class="base-div">
    <img src="base.png" class="base">
  </div>



  <div class="contentSection-door">
    <div class="content-door" data-t="13"><img src="images/door/d13.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="12"><img src="images/door/d12.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="11"><img src="images/door/d11.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="10"><img src="images/door/d10.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="9"><img src="images/door/d9.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="8"><img src="images/door/d8.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="7"><img src="images/door/d7.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="6"><img src="images/door/d6.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="5"><img src="images/door/d5.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="4"><img src="images/door/d4.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="3"><img src="images/door/d3.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="2"><img src="images/door/d2.png" class="alpha"></div>
    <div class="content-door" data-t="1"><img src="images/door/d1.png" class="alpha"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="selectSection-door">
    <button type="button" data-t="1">D1</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="2">D2</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="3">D3</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="4">D4</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="5">D5</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="6">D6</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="7">D7</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="8">D8</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="9">D9</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="10">D10</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="11">D11</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="12">D12</button>
    <button type="button" data-t="13">D13</button>
  </div>


</div>
```

However this could also be a prime candidate for CSS spriting, so it's worth to investigate that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot to mention I need to use pure JS, no jQuery. Your solution is using JQuery?

Comment: No jquery,  pure javasccript.  You might be thrown off by the [Template Litteral](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: It still flashes the white background on change of div/image. After I have pressed all the buttons there is no flash of the background.. is that just because the loops have been made and the results are stored in the memory? Is there an easy way to Add the chosen div BEFORE the displayed div is removed so there is no flash of the background div?

Comment: You may need to provide a more complete [mcve], hard to tell with borken images,  or are there other things we are missing. There should be no more loops now.

Comment: Here is a full fiddle. Can you see the flashing white background? https://jsfiddle.net/kdtwbfa7/

Comment: No flash in Safari, Chrome or Firefox on OSX

Comment: Thank you Jon. It must be the old version of firefox that i am using. Thanks so much for your time

Comment: No problem, you would still benefit from replacing your loop with the attribute selector, and you really should investigate spriting, it's less relevant than it once was but this is a good use case for it

Comment: Jon.. if you have time could you write your code in its most basic form so I can understand it?

Comment: What don't you understand about my code at the moment? Or are you referring to spriting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242249/discussion-between-jon-p-and-james).